# how make grading system in sql server table creation

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of student averages of four college year and field for find the average of four year degrees and the final field is for grading system.

My question: I want to make grade field value based on `final_avg` column. How can I achieve this?

For example if `final_avg < 50` then `grade = failed`, if `final_avg >= 50 and final_avg < 60` then `grade = satisfactory` and so on.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE averages_tbl(
    [avg_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Student_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [f_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [s_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [t_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [fu_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [final_avg]  AS ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg]),
    [grade] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
)
```

Comment: "I want to make" is not a question

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this `[final_avg]  AS ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg])` is not possible in a table creation, you would have to do it through a trigger. But I'm not really sure what are you asking to give you an answer.

Comment: [final_avg] AS ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg]) is possible and don't have a problem, but my question is not in this line, thank you.

Comment: What do u mean with `grading system`?

Comment: for example if final_avg < 50 then grade = failed, if final_avg >= 50 and final_avg < 60 then grade = satisfactory and so on.

Comment: `DO NOT` store data as computed column which may become invalid with more rows being added. Computed column should only be used to work with different column values within the same row. To view the data which will change with more rows being added to the table, use `VIEWS`. Write a view which will calculate the Final Average at runtime.

Comment: Why don't use a `VIEW` to calculate the `[final_avg]` and `[grade]`?

Comment: @M.Ali, sometimes we need to use computed columns when the number of record is more than usual or the computing columns need more time complexity. In this case when adding the record, computing columns should also be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
CREATE TABLE averages_tbl(
    [avg_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Student_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [f_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [s_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [t_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [fu_s_avg] [float] NULL,
    [final_avg]  AS ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg]),
    [grade] AS (CASE WHEN ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg]) < 50 THEN 'Failed' 
                     WHEN ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg]) between 50 and 59 THEN 'Satisfied'
                     ELSE 'Whatever' END)
)
```

Or with `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE averages_tbl DROP COLUMN [grade]

ALTER TABLE averages_tbl ADD [grade] AS (
    CASE WHEN ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg]) < 50 THEN 'Failed' 
         WHEN ((([f_s_avg]+[s_s_avg])+[t_s_avg])+[fu_s_avg]) between 50 and 59 THEN 'Satisfied'
         ELSE 'Passed' END)
```